# Having issues shuffling an array - returns null instead of a random integer

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random, shuffle

```
private static <T> void shuffle(T[] array){
    if(array==null || array.length < 2){
        return;
    }

    for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){
        int a = rng.nextInt(i+1);
        System.out.println(a);
        T temp = array[a];
        System.out.println(temp);
        array[a] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
}

static boolean checkSorted(ISort sorter, int size) {
    Integer[] data = new Integer[size];
    shuffle(data);
}
```

This the output when printing the variables `a` and `temp`:

> ```
> 0
> null
> 2
> null
> 0
> null
> 2
> null
> 0
> null
> 4
> null
> 7
> null
> 8
> null
> 6
> ```

I'm not sure why `temp` is *null* instead of *Integer*. Can anyone explain this to me? How should I modify this code in order to make it work?

Comment: can you provide code of ISort? is it your custom class?

Comment: `array` has no values, `array[a]` is null

Comment: @Raj  public interface ISort {
    <T extends java.lang.Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] ts);
}

Comment: `checkSorted()` needs to return a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer[] data = new Integer[size];` is an array of Integers, but until assigned all members in array are null, which you are printing. Initialize the array properly first:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[5];
array[0]= new Integer(0);
array[1]= new Integer(1);
```

Comment: Hi, i actually wanted to store the random number which is int a into the array but seems like my codes are totally wrong...

Answer (score 0):

In Java, every variable has a type. When you declare a variable without specifying a value, it will have, by default, a predefined value. If it's a variable that contains a reference to an *Object* (in other words, a variable of a [composite type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type)) it will have *null* as it's value. On the other hand, if it's a variable of a [*primitive type*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Primitive_Types), it will have different values according to it's type (default value for numbers is 0). See the table below for more details.

[image: Table with the default values for variables of different types]

(image taken from the Java's docs, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html))

With this in mind, we can now proceed to your code's behaviour. When you create an array of the type `Integer`, all of it's elements will be *null* by default. Note that `Integer` is an *object wrapper class* (see [type wrappers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class)), while `int` is a *primitive type*. If you had created an array of the type `int`, all it's elements would have, by default, the value *0*. That's why when you print `temp` *null* is being printed, and not a number. To solve that, you can assign values to the array's elements, like below:

```
Integer[] data = new Integer[size];

Random random = new Random();
for(Integer i: data) {
    i = random.nextInt(100); //assign a random value between 0 to 99
}
```